# Execute a task in TestNG when testng-result.xml file is generated

Tags: java, testng

We have an automation framework in which we are using TestNG to execute test cases. Once test cases finish executing we want to start the task which will call the java method to perform some task on TestNG generated file i.e. result file.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own [IExecutionListener](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.10-ga70d4da-115/javadoc/org/testng/IExecutionListener.html#onExecutionFinish--) which will be called at the end.

See [the listener part of the documentation](http://cbeust.github.io/testng/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) to understand how to deal with listeners.

Answer (score 1):

I think the maven-surefire listener configuration is what would work for you here:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <properties>
        <property>
          <name>listener</name>
          <value>com.mycompany.MyResultListener</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Then in your classpath you would need to create such a listener which would implement one of the testNG listeners: http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestNGListener.html

Examples taken from: [Listeners Examples](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Using_custom_listeners_and_reporters)

Comment: With maven and junit looks a good solution here. Will check same for gradle and testng

Comment: Im sitting too much in Junit lately.. for TestNG use the listener hat @juherr has advised. Along with the surefire config.. you should have a working solution..